# 3D CNN predicting mass center

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to build up a very simple 3D CNN where I want to predict the mass center of particles in 3D. So my input dimension reads (1000,3) (1000 particles with x,y,z coordinate) and the output reads (1,3) (since there is just one center to 1000 particles).

Of course I have many of these subsets which have 1000 particles and I will treat them as training and validation set; lets consider my training set consists of 2000 such boxes my final X_train shape reads (2000,1000,3) and Y_train is (2000,1,3).

How does the architecture for such CNN does look like?

I run always into dimensionality issues when trying to build one. Here is my try:

```
input_layer = Input((1000,3))

conv_layer1 = Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
conv_layer2 = Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu')(conv_layer1)

pooling_layer1 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv_layer2)

conv_layer3 = Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu')(pooling_layer1)
conv_layer4 = Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu')(conv_layer3)
pooling_layer2 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv_layer4)

pooling_layer2 = BatchNormalization()(pooling_layer2)
flatten_layer = Flatten()(pooling_layer2)

dense_layer1 = Dense(units=2048, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)
dense_layer1 = Dropout(0.4)(dense_layer1)
dense_layer2 = Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(dense_layer1)
dense_layer2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense_layer2)
output_layer = Dense(units=1, activation='relu')(dense_layer2)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

I get

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv3d_11 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 1000, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your input volumes have dimensions 32x32x32 (x,y,z) and are gray (one channel)

So your input must be:

```
Input((1000, 32, 32, 32, 1))
```